# MP3 Audio tag in Gecko-based (Firefox/Cometbird) browsers

Tags: html, firefox, audio, loops, mp3

I've been trying to work on a project to he able to turn loop on and off for the MP3 playing on a we page. I was using `<embed>` and tried changing the `loop=` property using a javascript `getElementByID`, but while the image swap would work, the song would still stay on the mode it was on at page load.

Someone else used the idea to use the `<audio>` tag, and made a togglefor `loop=`, and said it worked. I tried, and would not work. I went and tried on an example site, and it worked for OGG, but not MP3.

I researched it, and the only thing I could find was that Firefox didn't originally support MP3s due to LAME copyrights/patents, but started supporting the MP3 format in version 9.
What's even stranger, is that sometimes the player controls show up, sometimes they don't. I have random other information show up on the page on load, so can't say if it's random when it shows up, or related: but even when the controls load, the play button never works, and it doesn't start on autoplay. However, in Chrome, it loads up fine.

So to condense, when in IE, it loads the text to say it's not compatible with my browser, meaning I can have an `<embed>` for if it doesn't work: I just tried it. 
Firefox, on the other hand, acts like it WILL load it, and doesn't show the alt text.

I read about some people having trouble with OGGs, talking about a MAME type, but I don't really know anything about that stuff, yet...

I'd really like some ideas on what to do about this, because it doesn't ever even show the text to say it's not supported, it's like nothing's there in FF/CB, and MP3s SHOULD be supported for the past 4 full versions, which I'm assuming is why it doesn't say it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support MP3 in `<audio>`, precisely because it's still patented... I have no idea what made you think it's supported in Firefox 9.

Comment: Look things up before you post, changed this year.
http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/03/idealism-vs-pragmatism-mozilla-debates-supporting-h-264-video-playback/

In other words, if the SYSTEM supports it, they won't prevent it from working, like the originally did. Proof of this is further founded by the browser NOT returning the not supported text, when it attempts to load an MP3.

Comment: That post is about a plan to make it work in the _future_.  That code hasn't been checked in yet.

Comment: Then why does it stop there, and ATTEMPT to load, SOMETIMES showing the player? It should just skip to the next line in between the <audio> and </audio> tags. It doesn't.

Comment: The spec says that if you support _any_ codec in `<audio>`, you don't show the fallback content even if that codec is not present in the source list you're given.  As far as why there's an attempt to load, that depends on your markup.  Does your `<source>` element have a `type` attribute?

Comment: On the last account, Yes, I've tried marking it's type as MPEG and MP3. It randomly works or doesn't work, on whichever I've tried.

So on that note, since I use MP3s on my site, how could I design it so that GOOGLE plays the MP3 using <audio>, while Firefox used <embed>?

What you said explains why FF doesn't use the <embed> between the <audio> tags. Switching my sound file formats really isn't an option at this time, because they are from the site users...

Thanks. :)

Comment: You really can't do fallback from `<audio>` to `<embed>` with just markup.  You have to use script and `canPlayType`....

Comment: http://videojs.com/ might work (the problem is similar for audio and video).  Or crib off the examples at http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/html5-video-fallbacks/ ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the videojs...
I don't want my site to require more plugins than the normal ones used on any other sites... at least not until I make the browser bar... though once I do, I'm adding the music to that anyhow! :P